# Monospaced TextBlock using Segoe WP font

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone

I have a numerical value that ranges from 100-500 that changes every second or so. Because numerical characters for Segoe WP are variable widths, the text jumps when it changes.

Using the Segoe WP font in a XAML file; Is there a way to make numerical (or any) text render with monospaced (fixed width) characters?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "jump" but if you mean other content placement changes because the width of your numeric value changes, is it something you could just wrap in a parent element with a fixed width so the width of the numbers cant interact with other objects? Like, <border width="50"><textblock text="{Binding}"/></border>

Comment: By jump, I mean that TextBlock.ActualWidth width of the value "100" is different than the TextBlock.ActualWidth of "499". So when the value switches, so does the horizontal alignment.

Comment: Can't you just RightAlign the text and set the width to something you know is bigger than required?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A work around is to use the *"Segoe UI"* font family instead, which has monospaced numbers, and is reasonably similar.

Comment: From \u3905 to \u3915

Comment: @MohamedMansour: Did you even read my answer? It's the one in that pack that has exactly the same name as the one in my answer